# How to autoupdate or reload KIVY to fetch data from sqlite3 without re running the KIVY application

Tags: sqlite, spinner, kivy

I created a simple application, that can add data to a DB (sqlite).

> Button : Just an add button
>
> TexInput: Input names
>
> Spinner: show update of names

All are working, adding to DB and fetching from the DB.

my problem now is that how can i update my spinner to update its values without
closing or re-running the kivy application.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just update the Spinner *values* attribute

```
values = [r[0] for r in cursor.fetchall('select name from stuff_table')]
spinner.values = values #this will update the choices available
spinner.text = spinner.values[0]# choose default value...
```

Comment: Both writing and fetching to DB is in the same kivy appicaltion.
e.i. on my DB table i have this name Nike,Mike,Bob

when i run my Kivy App, my spinner is showing me Nike,Mike,Bob
if i add another name say John to my DB, the spinner is not showing John. Until i re-run my kivy App.

Comment: Got it, thanks @Yoav. i was sending the spinner values as "return" value . with logic code given, it works. Thanks